# Use R to combine duplicate columns

Tags: r

I have a table with 4 columns with columns 1,3 and columns 2,4 representing the same variable.

```
Codes    Description        Codes     Description
xxxxx    describes xxxxx    zzzzz     describes zzzzz
yyyyy    describes yyyyy    12345     describes 12345
```

I want to convert the table into

```
Codes    Description       
xxxxx    describes xxxxx    
zzzzz    describes zzzzz
yyyyy    describes yyyyy  
12345    describes 12345
```

Right now I am doing this use by :

```
df_temp <- df[,3:4]
df <- df[, - c(3, 4)]
df <- rbind(df, df_temp)
```

But I have to do it for several table and my method doesn't seem very efficient.  Would it be possible to do this using %>% or writing a function?

Comment: If the column order never changes why not `bind_r <- function(df) rbind(df[,1:2], df[,3:4])`?

Comment: are you trying to combine all of the columns from all of the tables into one large table or are you attempting to keep separate combined tables 2 column tables for each one of the four column tables?

Comment: ideally I would like to easily combine all of the tables into one large table?

Answer (score 3):

A list-based approach with `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

df %>% map(as.character) %>%    # convert factors to character, leave as list
    split(names(.)) %>%    # split list by column names
    map_df(flatten_chr)   # unlist each element and reassemble to data.frame

## # A tibble: 4 × 2
##   Codes     Description
##   <chr>           <chr>
## 1 xxxxx describes xxxxx
## 2 yyyyy describes yyyyy
## 3 zzzzz describes zzzzz
## 4 12345 describes 12345
```

or in base R,

```
as.data.frame(lapply(split(lapply(df, 
                                  as.character), 
                           names(df)), 
                     unlist))

##   Codes     Description
## 1 xxxxx describes xxxxx
## 2 yyyyy describes yyyyy
## 3 zzzzz describes zzzzz
## 4 12345 describes 12345
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `duplicated` function to dynamically identify and `rbind` the duplicate columns:

```
combine_duplicates <- function(df) {
   duplicate_columns <- duplicated(colnames(df))
   return(rbind(df[,duplicate_columns], df[,!duplicate_columns]))
}
combine_duplicates(df)
```

This will work on any table, provided the duplicate columns are always in the same order as the original column names (e.g. `c("Codes", "Description", "Codes", "Description")` will work, `c("Codes", "Description", "Description", "Codes")` will not) and that there are no extra columns without duplicates in the table.

Comment: line 2 should read  duplicate_columns <- duplicated(colnames(df))

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed the typo

Comment: .@ScottRitchie - Do you have any suggestions on how to perform this irrespective of how the columns are arranged?

Answer (score 2):

A generalisable answer that will work for any number of pairs of variables in a somewhat sensible order (code,desc,code,desc or code,code,desc,desc) is:

```
names(dat) <- make.unique(names(dat)[c(1:2,1:length(dat))])[-(1:2)]
#[1] "Codes.1"       "Description.1" "Codes.2"       "Description.2"
reshape(dat, direction="long", varying=1:4, timevar=NULL)
#    Codes    Description id
#1.1 xxxxx describesxxxxx  1
#2.1 yyyyy describesyyyyy  2
#1.2 zzzzz describeszzzzz  1
#2.2 12345 describes12345  2
```

Comment: .@thelatemail - Will this work on any data frame irrespective of whether we know it has duplicate column name or not?